# Delete all items in DynamoDB table using Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm trying to write a simple ruby script that delete all items in a DynamoDB table, but I'm having trouble understand which argument to pass to "delete_items", this is what I have so far:

```
dynamoDB = Aws::DynamoDB::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

dynamoDB.tables.each do |table|
  puts "Table #{table.name}"
  scan_output = table.scan({
    select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
    })

  scan_output.items.each do |item|
    keys = item.keys
    table.delete_item({
      key: ???
    })
  end
end
```

I tried passing the item, or item.keys - both did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually wrote this script which delete all records from all tables (not very useful for most cases, but for mine it was exactly what I needed, as I was using it in a dedicated testing account):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'aws-sdk'

dynamoDB = Aws::DynamoDB::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

dynamoDB.tables.each do |table|
  puts "Table #{table.name}"
  scan_output = table.scan({
    select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
    })

  scan_output.items.each do |item|
    item_key = Hash.new
    table.key_schema.each do |k|
      item_key[k.attribute_name] = item[k.attribute_name]
    end
    table.delete_item({
      key: item_key
    })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to scan and delete all the items from DynamoDB table though I am not sure why can't you delete the table and recreate if you would like to delete all the items from a table.

Please note that this is **not a recommended approach** unless you have some very specific use case. This would cost you as the code reads the item from table and then delete the item.

**Code:-**

You may need to change the table name and key value in the below code. In the below code, the table name used is `files` and its key value is `fileName`.

If you have both partition key and sort key, then you need to set both the values. The `files` table has only partition key.

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

require "aws-sdk-core"

# Configure SDK

# use credentials file at .aws/credentials
Aws.config[:credentials] = Aws::SharedCredentials.new
Aws.config[:region] = "us-west-2"

# point to DynamoDB Local, comment out this line to use real DynamoDB
Aws.config[:dynamodb] = { endpoint: "http://localhost:8000" }

dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new

tableName = "files"

scanParams = {
  table_name: tableName
}

puts "Scanning files table."

begin
  loop do
    result = dynamodb.scan(scanParams)

    result.items.each{|files|
      puts "Item :" + "#{files}"
      puts "Going to delete item :" + "#{files["fileName"]}"

      deleteParams = {
        table_name: tableName,
        key: {
          fileName: files["fileName"]

        }
      }
      begin
        deleteResult = dynamodb.delete_item(deleteParams)
        puts "Deleted item." + files["fileName"]            

      rescue  Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ServiceError => error
        puts "Unable to delete item:"
        puts "#{error.message}"
      end

    }


    break if result.last_evaluated_key.nil?
    puts "Scanning for more..."
    scanParams[:exclusive_start_key] = result.last_evaluated_key

  end

rescue  Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ServiceError => error
  puts "Unable to scan:"
  puts "#{error.message}"
end
```

Comment: You assume I know the table name, while I would like to delete all records from all tables. I will post the script I eventually used.